# Linux bash: find folders containing specific text

Tags: arrays, linux, bash, text, directory

I learned how to use a script yesterday that would display all files containing the entered text.

```
echo "enter serial number"
read number

matchfiles=(`find /home/data_files -maxdepth 1 -name "*$number*" -type f -exec basename {} \;`)

COUNTER=${#matchfiles[@]}

echo serial number data folder found:
until [  $COUNTER -lt 0 ]; do
echo ${matchfiles[$COUNTER]}
let COUNTER-=1
done
```

If the number 12 was entered it would output all files with the number 12 contained in the filename'

For ex:

```
enter serial number
12
file12.fee
12file.foo
file.12
```

Im looking for a way to do the exact same thing but with directories

so the output would be

```
enter serial number
12
folder12
12folder
```

I need the folder names contained in an array so they may be used later for manipulating the data within them.

Comment: `-type d` will restrict the search to dir names.

Comment: @karakfa Of course... haha. thank you!

Answer (score 1):

```
find {path} -name "*$number*" -type d -exec readlink -f {} \;
```

if your optional {path} is relative, you want `readlink -f` is to convert relative paths to absolute path.  You may want to add back `-maxdepth` if you want to restrict recursive search in the dir path.